# Extract firmware of my camera (Lumix MG5)

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware

I bought a Camera (Lumix GM5), but I can't change the language of it.

The easy way is to send it back to Amazon, but I want to try to change it
by modifying the firmware before.

So, I used `binwalk` to analyze the firmware:

```
root@ec5b1dd5bce3:~# binwalk GM5__V11.bin 
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
6789427       0x679933        MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 9
30718920      0x1D4BBC8       MySQL ISAM index file Version 1
31869478      0x1E64A26       ZBOOT firmware header, header size: 32 
bytes, load address: 0x29F4F830, start address: 0x9692295D, checksum: 0x11837327, version: 0xB1437316, image size: 1837825596 bytes
```

I see that there is `misam` compressed data.
Maybe I can change the language here, maybe not.

So to exract it with binwalk again I did :

```
[root@ec5b1dd5bce3:~/_GM5__V11.bin.extracted# binwalk -D '.sql:myd:myisamchk' GM5__V11.bin
```

which give me two files:

```
binwalk 679933.myd 
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
0             0x0             MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 9
23929493      0x16D2295       MySQL ISAM index file Version 1
25080051      0x17EB0F3       ZBOOT firmware header, header size: 32 bytes, load address: 0x29F4F830, start address: 0x9692295D, checksum: 0x11837327, version: 0xB1437316, image size: 1837825596 bytes
```

And :

```
[root@ec5b1dd5bce3:~/_GM5__V11.bin.extracted# binwalk 1D4BBC8.myd 
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
0             0x0             MySQL ISAM index file Version 1
1150558       0x118E5E        ZBOOT firmware header, header size: 32 bytes, load address: 0x29F4F830, start address: 0x9692295D, checksum: 0x11837327, version: 0xB1437316, image size: 1837825596 bytes
```

But now when I try to use `myisamchk` on my new files it failed :

```
root@ec5b1dd5bce3:~/_GM5__V11.bin.extracted# myisamchk 679933.myd 
myisamchk: error: '679933.myd' is not a MyISAM-table
```

I guess it's because I still have the "ZBOOT firmware header" in my **.myd** files.

So I was wondering, what is the proper way to extract only specific "signatures" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Binwalk identifies parts based on magic values, so type of the parts may not be correct. Based on the part's offset and header values, the binwalk result does not seem to be valid.

Comment: @ebux I have reached the limit of what I can currently do (see below). Is it possible to go further without physical access to the device?

Comment: The header describes the parts in the file (part name[0:0xc], start offset (+0x200=offset in file), size), but the data seems to be encrypted somehow. Physical access may solve the problem, if you can read out the plain firmware or serial port is active.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the link to the firmware update: [Joint update service for Four Thirds lenses](http://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/dsc/download/fts/index2.html)

These results are most likely false positives. After the first ~1536 bytes the data is encoded and essentially random (very high entropy). ZBOOT firmware is typically found in TVs and ISAM and MYISAM files are used by the MySQL [MyISAM storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), which seems unlikely to be running on an embedded system with significant memory constraints like a digital camera.

### Analysis

**Signatures**

Here are the 3-byte sequences of the signatures for MySQL files (from [`binwalk/sql`](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/blob/master/src/binwalk/magic/sql)):

```
\xfe\xfe\x03    MySQL MISAM index file
\xfe\xfe\x05    MySQL ISAM index file
\xfe\xfe\x06    MySQL ISAM compressed data file
\xfe\xfe\x07    MySQL MISAM compressed data file
```

A shorter byte sequence has a higher likelihood of appearing in a 31901184-byte binary file with very high entropy.

Here is the signature for a ZBOOT firmware header (from [`binwalk/firmware`](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/blob/master/src/binwalk/magic/firmware)):

```
#Firmware header used by some TV's
0   string      FNIB        ZBOOT firmware header, header size: 32 bytes,
>8  lelong      x           load address: 0x%.8X,
>12 lelong      x           start address: 0x%.8X,
>16 lelong      x           checksum: 0x%.8X,
>20 lelong      x           version: 0x%.8X,
>24 lelong      <1          invalid
>24 lelong      x           image size: %d bytes
```

Looking at the bytes `binwalk` detects as a ZBOOT signature using `hexdump` confirms the scan output:

```
$ hexdump -C -s 31869478 -n 24 GM5__V11.bin
01e64a26  46 4e 49 42 ba 86 a0 69  30 f8 f4 29 5d 29 92 96  |FNIB...i0..)])..|
01e64a36  27 73 83 11 16 73 43 b1                           |'s...sC.|
```

A load address of `0x29F4F830`, start address of `0x9692295D`, version number of `0xB1437316`, and image size of 1837825596 bytes all appear to be incorrect. A firmware image 1.8 GB in size implies at least that much space in memory for the image to be loaded into, which does not seem correct for a digital camera.

**Entropy Analysis**

This is the entropy plot generated by `binwalk`:
[image: binwalk entropy plot]

The very smooth line close to 1 [suggests compression or encryption](http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/). More support for this is provided by [`ent`](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/):

```
$ ent GM5__V11.bin
Entropy = 7.999995 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 31901184 byte file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 31901184 samples is 235.87, and randomly
would exceed this value 79.95 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.4853 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.142165006 (error 0.02 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is -0.000084 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```

According to tests performed by [devttys0](http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/),

> Applying these tests to a (admittedly small) sample of files with
>   varying size which had been put through different
>   compression/encryption algorithms showed the following correlations:
>
> - Large deviations in the chi square distribution, or large percentages of error in the Monte Carlo approximation are sure signs
>     of compression.
> - Very accurate pi calculations (< .01% error) are sure signs of encryption.
> - Lower chi values (< 300) with higher pi error (> .03%) are indicative of compression.
> - Higher chi values (> 300) with lower pi errors (< .03%) are indicative of encryption.

Since the results from `ent` were a chi square distribution of 235.87 and a pi calculation error of 0.02 percent, it is difficult to tell which using just these heuristics.

**File Header**

The header is not encoded and can be analyzed separately from the encoded portion of the binary. To get a sense of its structure, here is a visualization of the header created using [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/):

[image: header]

This can aid in investigating a hexdump of the header:

```
$ hexdump -C header.bin
00000000  55 50 44 00 00 02 00 00  00 02 00 00 47 4d 35 00  |UPD.........GM5.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 10 01 10 01  |................|
00000020  04 00 00 00 48 17 27 01  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |....H.'.........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 c4 e6 01  |................|
00000040  49 a1 b1 e2 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |I...............|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200  70 61 6e 61 73 6f 6e 69  63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |panasonic.......|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000220  09 1a d7 cd 27 82 30 17  85 18 17 7b 0a fe 57 de  |....'.0....{..W.|
00000230  ba 20 30 41 f1 97 64 12  a0 a3 39 65 85 45 28 6c  |. 0A..d...9e.E(l|
00000240  f8 2d 00 75 99 6a 32 73  1d 0a fe c7 8d 9b af e5  |.-.u.j2s........|
00000250  8a 17 2c 78 64 37 b1 cb  24 ee 69 d1 b0 9a 1e fb  |..,xd7..$.i.....|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000002a0  55 50 44 00 00 02 00 00  00 02 00 00 47 4d 35 00  |UPD.........GM5.|
000002b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 10 01 10 01  |................|
000002c0  04 00 00 00 48 17 27 01  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |....H.'.........|
000002d0  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 c4 e6 01  |................|
000002e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 70 72 6f 67  |............prog|
000002f0  72 61 6d 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 00 00 00 00 80 00  |ram.............|
00000300  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  e6 ce 3a 07 64 fd 56 e0  |..........:.d.V.|
00000310  f2 55 d4 41 2d 30 b1 f9  f7 3b 52 82 b3 33 c0 fe  |.U.A-0...;R..3..|
00000320  80 f1 6d c1 18 33 07 8c  84 03 c7 fb f9 8b de 15  |..m..3..........|
00000330  a6 9e 7c ba ee be 5f 6a  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..|..._j........|
00000340  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  67 75 69 72 65 73 00 00  |........guires..|
00000350  00 00 00 00 00 04 80 00  00 00 c0 00 00 00 80 00  |................|
00000360  03 00 00 00 5e 59 a4 51  17 17 91 01 88 1b 5b e4  |....^Y.Q......[.|
00000370  59 05 6f aa 86 75 95 24  a3 a6 0f 57 07 87 d1 38  |Y.o..u.$...W...8|
00000380  b3 53 05 c2 52 e3 63 b6  ab 09 1d 0d 14 81 ae 69  |.S..R.c........i|
00000390  de 76 1b 11 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.v..............|
000003a0  00 00 00 00 70 72 6f 67  72 61 6d 32 00 00 00 00  |....program2....|
000003b0  00 04 40 01 00 00 36 00  00 00 40 01 03 00 00 00  |..@...6...@.....|
000003c0  90 dd 3e 4a 19 c6 00 85  71 f1 62 3e 4d 84 9f 24  |..>J....q.b>M..$|
000003d0  5b 27 94 73 f4 3e 3b 13  f8 b7 63 e6 c9 4a 53 a5  |['.s.>;...c..JS.|
000003e0  39 c4 94 f0 01 50 3f 7d  66 6b 16 91 31 be 58 9f  |9....P?}fk..1.X.|
000003f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000400  61 72 6d 63 6f 64 65 00  00 00 00 00 00 04 76 01  |armcode.......v.|
00000410  00 00 34 00 00 00 76 01  03 00 00 00 c7 e1 96 1a  |..4...v.........|
00000420  12 18 64 68 6f 32 7a 3b  f8 2b 18 d1 59 6e 39 a4  |..dho2z;.+..Yn9.|
00000430  4b a1 3b 0e 63 fc 7c d1  a6 c9 10 b1 4e 1a 90 e6  |K.;.c.|.....N...|
00000440  e9 fb ec 36 92 7b dc 2b  29 e5 b4 b0 00 00 00 00  |...6.{.+).......|
00000450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 6f 74 68 65  |............othe|
00000460  72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 aa 01 00 00 38 00  |r.............8.|
00000470  00 00 b4 01 03 00 00 00  a2 36 81 24 c4 43 60 d8  |.........6.$.C`.|
00000480  05 96 82 00 24 9b d0 f2  01 72 74 8a 4b 41 0a b6  |....$....rt.KA..|
00000490  c2 ae 74 54 b2 b0 74 54  3e 8e 15 3b e1 b1 0b d8  |..tT..tT>..;....|
000004a0  24 4d 11 32 c6 d4 78 fc  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |$M.2..x.........|
000004b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  65 65 70 5f 6f 77 5f 61  |........eep_ow_a|
000004c0  00 00 00 00 00 04 e2 01  00 00 02 00 00 00 fa 01  |................|
000004d0  03 00 00 00 b3 45 11 95  0d 13 6f 0d d1 7a 2d 4e  |.....E....o..z-N|
000004e0  86 72 d7 65 0c 2b db a9  fb 21 c8 93 a3 9b 95 cb  |.r.e.+...!......|
000004f0  0a bd 38 87 84 86 28 33  c3 e7 ca 1c 74 5b 10 34  |..8...(3....t[.4|
00000500  65 20 02 aa 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |e ..............|
00000510  00 00 00 00 65 65 70 5f  6f 77 5f 62 00 00 00 00  |....eep_ow_b....|
00000520  00 04 e4 01 00 00 02 00  00 00 fc 01 03 00 00 00  |................|
00000530  b3 45 11 95 0d 13 6f 0d  d1 7a 2d 4e 86 72 d7 65  |.E....o..z-N.r.e|
00000540  0c 2b db a9 fb 21 c8 93  a3 9b 95 cb 0a bd 38 87  |.+...!........8.|
00000550  74 e7 e8 b9 78 c8 63 0a  85 b7 4a 2b 7c fc 6f e0  |t...x.c...J+|.o.|
00000560  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000570  65 65 70 5f 61 64 6a 66  69 78 00 00 00 04 e6 01  |eep_adjfix......|
00000580  00 c0 00 00 00 00 fe 01  03 00 00 00 72 be 21 58  |............r.!X|
00000590  3a cd 1f 9f 93 d9 8b 9d  7d ac ef 1a b7 28 c1 31  |:.......}....(.1|
000005a0  29 df cc 02 a2 ef a9 ae  30 b6 ea cc b7 89 e4 78  |).......0......x|
000005b0  4b d1 60 72 c8 77 e2 b5  d6 03 03 c5 00 00 00 00  |K.`r.w..........|
000005c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
```

Between the visualization and the hexdump of the header, it looks like there are 10 or 11 blocks of bytes seperated by sequences of `0x00` bytes and each of these blocks begins with ASCII data. Here are the human-readable strings:

```
UPD
GM5
panasonic
UPD
GM5
program
guires
program2
armcode
other
eep_ow_a
eep_ow_b
eep_adjfix
```

It is difficult to determine what, if any, significance the data in the unencoded first 1536 bytes in the file have without more information.

**Update:**

I looked for patterns in the nonzero byte blocks and observed that the 8 strings below are followed by the byte sequence `00 00 00 04`:

```
 program
 guires
 program2
 armcode
 other
 eep_ow_a
 eep_ow_b
 eep_adjfix
```

[image: observation 1]

Also observed repetitions of `03 00 00 00`:
[image: observation 3]

The padding between these 8 blocks consisted of 16 `00` bytes:

[image: observation2]